# Prestashop attributes same for all products

Tags: attributes, prestashop

Ciao,
I have a Prestashop shop, I have more than 1000 products (shoes) and I have to set the attributes (show number) for every shoe.
The attributes are 14 for every shoe (shoe number going from 33 to 46 - european size).

I found out I have to set them one by one... Is this even fair? Is there a way to set them all/some to have those attributes without going into editing one by one?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look to the mysql tables you can detect the pattern and automatize with an script. It'll be the same pattern increasing the product id. Other possibility is to generate csv file of product combinations and import from the backoffice.

Comment: You can find useful information inside ps_product_attribute, ps_product_attribute_combination, ps_attribute and ps_attribute_lang tables. With a little bit of patience and some php scripting to insert the new information on these tables, you'll get it.